# Can I use my O365 Custom domain name as my Azure AD Domain Services domain name?

Tags: microsoft-office-365, entra-id

I have an existing O365 tenant with a custom domain name.

I also have a couple of VM's running in Azure and for all sorts of reasons I would like to add Azure Active Directory Domain Services.

Where it comes to chosing the domain name, the Azure Portal UI is defaulting to the existing O365 custom domain name.

I am a little unlcear as to whether I should choose this option, or change it to some other domain I own.

It's not a question I have been able to find a direct answer to although the documentation does say: *If you create a custom domain name, take care with existing DNS namespaces. It's recommended to use a domain name separate from any existing Azure or on-premises DNS name space*.

Can anyone tell me if I have to use a different domain name ?

Comment: if your domain would be abc.de then you csn use any subdomain like ad.abc.de but dobt use abc.de as ad domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommendation here would be to use a sperate domain name. There's a good write up about this here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/tutorial-create-instance#create-a-managed-domain

Make sure to a pick a routable domain name though if you're planning to access LDAPS over the internet, so you may be able to get a certificate that matches the FQDN.